# Записать вывод в консоль в файл, продолжая выводить вывод в консоль

Tags: python

Есть скрипт, который в процессе исполнения задает пользователю вопросы и для продолжения выполнения необходимо правильно ответить на вопросы. У меня получилось с помощью следующего кода выводить вывод как консоль, так и в файл. Но, к сожалению, запись в файл работает только до первого вопроса, после ответа на который в консоль продолжает выводиться вывод, но в файл не пишет. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, почему так происходит. Спасибо.

```
import sys 
class Logger:
 
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.console = sys.stdout
        self.file = open(filename, 'w')
 
    def write(self, message):
        self.console.write(message)
        self.file.write(message)
 
    def flush(self):
        self.console.flush()
        self.file.flush()
 
path = 'file.txt'
sys.stdout = Logger(path)
```

Comment: Проблема не воспроизводится: добавил два print - прекрасно пишет и обе строки и в консоль, и в файл. Добавьте больше кода.